# Create Circle from Min Max Lat Long Latitude Longitude

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2, gis, geospatial

The following TSQL example will create a **RECTANGLE** from Min Max Latitude Longitude

```
DECLARE @MinLat     VARCHAR (10)    = N'53.811446';
DECLARE @MaxLat     VARCHAR (10)    = N'53.809166';
DECLARE @MinLong    VARCHAR (10)    = N'-1.594991';
DECLARE @MaxLong    VARCHAR (10)    = N'-1.591515';

DECLARE
    @boundingRect   VARCHAR (150)
    ,@geom          GEOMETRY;

SET @boundingRect = 'POLYGON((' +   @MinLong + ' ' + @MinLat + ', ' + 
                                    @MaxLong + ' ' + @MinLat + ', ' + 
                                    @MaxLong + ' ' + @MaxLat + ', ' + 
                                    @MinLong + ' ' + @MaxLat + ', ' + 
                                    @MinLong + ' ' + @MinLat 
                            + '))';
SET @geom = @boundingRect;
SELECT @geom;
```

[image]

How can I create a **CIRCLE** from same coordinates? Assume the straight line between the coordinates represent the diameter of a circle.

Comment: How would that circle look like? The minimum number of points needed to create a circle is either two points where one of them is the middle point and the other on the circle (so you have the radius), or 3 points on the circle. You can't have a circle touching all 4 points of your rectangle since it's not a square.

Comment: Well I have two points. A straight line on either side of a circumference. directly opposite each other.One end of this line to the centre would be the radius.

Comment: So you have two points where the straight line between them is the diameter or the circle?

Comment: That's right, yes

Comment: I'm just curious. Why do you do that in T-SQL?

Comment: I'm working on a system that stores circles drawn on in an application as a diameter in the db. I need the create the "geospatial" circle to calculate whether movement events (lat/long geospatial points) occurred within said circles.

Comment: If you really do have latitudes and longitudes, you should be using `geography`, not `geometry`.

Answer (score 0):

Could this be of help? I can't test it right now

```
SET @boundingCircle = 'CURVEPOLYGON(CIRCULARSTRING(' 
                     + @MaxLong + ' ' + (@MinLat+(@MaxLat-@MinLat)/2) + ', ' 
                     + @MinLong + ' ' + (@MinLat+(@MaxLat-@MinLat)/2) + ', ' 
                     + @MaxLong + ' ' + (@MinLat+(@MaxLat-@MinLat)/2) + ', ' 
                     + '))';
```

Comment: Thanks for this but `CURVEPOLYGON` was introduced in SQL2012, I'm working on 2008r2.

Comment: I see, sorry I didn't notice..!

Answer (score 0):

I may have worked this out based on the comments from @ZoharPeled

Using a combination of [STDistance](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/spatial-geometry/stdistance-geometry-data-type?view=sql-server-2017), [STCentroid](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/spatial-geometry/stcentroid-geometry-data-type?view=sql-server-2017) and [STBuffer](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/spatial-geometry/stbuffer-geometry-data-type?view=sql-server-2017)

**Note**: The doc for STCentroid says this was introduced from 2012 but it works on 2008r2

Use STCentroid to get the centre point of a polygon
Use STDistance to get the radius 
Use STBuffer to generate a Polygon (with multiple points) of the circle

So, following on from the code example in the question
Get the centre point

```
DECLARE @g geometry;  
SET @g = geometry::STGeomFromText(@boundingRect, 0);  
SELECT @g.STCentroid().ToString();
```

gives you

```
POINT (-1.5932529999990948 53.8103059999994)
```

Get the radius

```
DECLARE @h geometry;  
SET @g = geometry::STGeomFromText('POINT (-1.594991 53.811446)', 0);    --one end of the radius
SET @h = geometry::STGeomFromText('POINT (-1.5932529999990948 53.8103059999994)', 0);  --from STCentroid
SELECT @g.STDistance(@h);   --0.00207851966661527
```

gives you

```
0.00207851966661527
```

Create the Polygon Circle

```
DECLARE @poly NVARCHAR(MAX)
SET @g = geometry::STGeomFromText('POINT (-1.5932529999990948 53.8103059999994)', 0);  
SELECT @poly = @g.STBuffer(0.00207851966661527).ToString(); --from STDistance()
SET @h = geometry::STGeomFromText(@poly, 0); 
SELECT @h
```

Gives you

[image]

Now, is there a less convoluted way to do this?